# Data manipulation in MySQL using window functions

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I've a table in my database with record of an agent. The record looks like
[image: Initial record]

Here, Site ID is a place where the Agent 1001 visits at logs himself in at TimeIn and then logs out of that site at TimeOut and raises some tickets and its corresponding amount. Now, If the site is not changed then I want to aggregate these records as shown in the table given below:
[image: Manipulated final record]

I am using MySQL database to do this. Using window functions I can find out consecutive matching Site ID and then mark it as some flag_variable (let's say 1) in a new column.
Now, for these rows where flag=1, I want to update current row TimeOut = next row Timeout. For three or more consecutive record of same Site ID this approach will not work, then we should need a recursive approach I guess.
My question is how can we do this update in the current table and remove redundant records in the table using MySQL syntax.

Comment: It will match better to post tables data as text, not images. Also you can use one of online services such as https://sqlize.online to post tables and queries

Comment: Instead of using the next row's data, get the max of timeout with the same flag.

Comment: @Shadow can you please explain. I couldn't understand what are you talking about.

Comment: If you are flagging consecutive visits to the same site ID with the same flag, then you can group by the flag and get the min of the time in column and the max of the time out column.

Comment: @Shadow your approach seemed to be fair at first, I was able to mark consecutive visits with a flag 1.But  suppose we have consecutive sites at row 1, 2 and 3 and then for same site we have consecutive entries at row 11 and 12. Now, all the consecutive entries in row 1,2,3 and 11,12 are marked as flag 1. Now, when I take max(timeout) by grouping with siteid and flag timeout at row 12 will be considered as max time. But I want in rows 1,2,3 max time should give timeout of row 3 and in row 11, 12 max timeout as timeout of row 12. Can we differentiate between flags also using any method.

Comment: You have not shared any attempts, so cannot help you to fix anything

Comment: @Shadow I am sharing my approach here. [sqlize_example] (https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/dd5af810eea76a4e66afa0e126aaa38c/) You can see in Row 9,10,11 and 14 and 15 when I take minimum of TimeIn or maximum of TimeOut wrong values are taken. For row 9,10,11 I want min_TimeIn to be minimum TimeIn of rows (9,10,11) and max_TimeOut to be maximum TimeOut of rows (9,10,11) which are consecutive. Row 14 and 15 should be treated as different consecutive entities and their min_TimeIn and MaxTimeOut should depend on rows (14,15).